# Perl: how to resolve object type inside the sub?

Tags: perl, oop

```
my sub method {
  my ($self, $o_class_1) = @_;
  my $o_class_2 = new class();
  $o_class_2->exec # this gives me auto completion of the method name exec() in pycharm, since it knows the objects's class
  $o_class_1-> # this has no auto completion, since it doesn't know what kind of object it is.
}
```

Is there a way somehow in Perl to "tell" that `$o_class_1 is` object of class?

Comment: You are asking question that pertains to an IDE, but you don't mention which IDE.

Comment: IDE is named in the code block, scroll right or ctrl+f `pycharm`, so effectively any Jetbrains IDE → Camelcade.

Comment: thanks for the comments, the IDE does not matter in this case, the problem is that perl could not interpret what kind of object's class ($o_class_i object) will be given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Annotate the declaration with the type.](https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/wiki/Subs-resolution-status)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a random scalar variable and you want to find out what it is a reference to, you can use the [`ref()`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/ref) function. This returns:

- The empty string if the variable doesn't contain a reference
- A string ("SCALAR", "ARRAY", "HASH", etc) indicating the type of reference if the variable contains an unblessed reference
- The name of the class if the variable contains a blessed reference (i.e. an it's an object)

But I'm not sure that this is what you want to know. Your question seems to imply that you're trying to access this information in an IDE.